# Applescript error: Can't make class xxxx of application "Photos" into type list, record or text

Tags: applescript, photo

I'm stumped and need some help debugging some AppleScript i have written. For my needs, I have exported my Apple Photos library to an external disk location, and written the media item ID of each photo to the metadata embedded in the file. This way, when the external file's keywords are updated, I can update Apple Photos to reflect that. Here's the relevant script:

```
tell application "Finder"
set theFile to "G-DRIVE:Media:photo:2015:12:2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF" as alias

set fileString to my convertPathToPOSIXString(theFile)  
set photosID to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -config /Volumes/G-DRIVE/Scratch/customConfig -if 'defined $JustinApplePhotosID' -s -s -s -xmp:JustinApplePhotosID " & "'" & fileString & "'"
end tell

tell application "Photos"
set updateItems to (get media items whose id is photosID)
set numItems to the number of updateItems
if the number of updateItems is equal to 1 then
    set mediaItem to the first item in updateItems
        set keywordResult to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -s -s -s -keywords " & "'" & fileString & "'"
        set keywordArray to my theSplit(keywordResult, ",")
        set the keywords of mediaItem to keywordArray

        if keywordArray contains "5*****" and album "5 Stars" does not contain {mediaItem} then
            add {mediaItem} to album "5 Stars"
        else if keywordArray does not contain "5*****" and album "5 Stars" contains {mediaItem} then
            syncSmartAlbum("5 Stars")
        end if
end if
end tell

on syncSmartAlbum(dumbAlbumName)
tell application "Photos"
    set smartAlbumName to dumbAlbumName & " Smart"
    set smartAlbum to album smartAlbumName
    tell album dumbAlbumName to if exists then delete
    set newDumbAlbum to make new album named dumbAlbumName
    add (get media items of smartAlbum) to newDumbAlbum
end tell
end syncSmartAlbum
```

Here's the result when run on this test file:

```
    tell current application
    offset of "." in "FEN.3700_CSD_s31m35h11_ta_52-21-5102/21/5102/otohp/aideM/EVIRD-G/semuloV/"
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    get name extension of alias "G-DRIVE:Media:photo:2015:12:2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF"
    get name extension of alias "G-DRIVE:Media:photo:2015:12:2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -config /Volumes/G-DRIVE/Scratch/customConfig -if 'defined $JustinApplePhotosID' -s -s -s -xmp:JustinApplePhotosID '/Volumes/G-DRIVE/Media/photo/2015/12/2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF'"
end tell
tell current application
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -config /Volumes/G-DRIVE/Scratch/customConfig -if 'defined $JustinApplePhotosID' -s -s -s -xmp:JustinApplePhotosID '/Volumes/G-DRIVE/Media/photo/2015/12/2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF'"
end tell
tell application "Photos"
    get every media item whose id = "tshx+Vk5TFC47a8Q5EeCiw"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -s -s -s -keywords '/Volumes/G-DRIVE/Media/photo/2015/12/2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF'"
end tell
tell current application
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -s -s -s -keywords '/Volumes/G-DRIVE/Media/photo/2015/12/2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF'"
end tell
tell application "Photos"
    set keywords of media item id "tshx+Vk5TFC47a8Q5EeCiw" to {"4****"}
    get album "5 Stars"
    album id "b72G+JL2R5qyTJ%w0fAcqQ" contains {media item id "tshx+Vk5TFC47a8Q5EeCiw"}
    get album id "b72G+JL2R5qyTJ%w0fAcqQ"
end tell
tell current application
    current date
    (*2019:11:16:13:18:08: Error reading or setting keywords for /Volumes/G-DRIVE/Media/photo/2015/12/2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF with error: Can’t make «class IPal» id "b72G+JL2R5qyTJ%w0fAcqQ" of application "Photos" into type list, record or text.*)
    open for access file "G-DRIVE:Scratch:Logs:UpdateKeywords.log" with write permission
    write "2019:11:16:13:18:08: Error reading or setting keywords for /Volumes/G-DRIVE/Media/photo/2015/12/2015-12-25_at_11h53m13s_DSC_0073.NEF with error: Can’t make «class IPal» id \"b72G+JL2R5qyTJ%w0fAcqQ\" of application \"Photos\" into type list, record or text.
" to 273 starting at eof
    close access 273
end tell
Result:
true
```

The error at issue appears to be: Can’t make «class IPal» id "b72G+JL2R5qyTJ%w0fAcqQ" of application "Photos" into type list, record or text

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Just noticing the absence of the `convertPathToPOSIXString()` handler definition and curious as to what it does. But, since your variable `theFile` is an `alias` object, you can get it's posix path by: `set fileString to the POSIX path of theFile`.  You don't need the `tell app "Finder"` wrapper at all: none of the operations within that block are performed by _Finder_ (**`do shell script`** definitely isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Apparently can't just ask whether an album "contains" an item.
Here's the fix:

```
        set FiveStarPhotos to (id of media items of album "5 Stars")

        if keywordArray contains "5*****" and FiveStarPhotos does not contain {mediaItem} then
            add {mediaItem} to album "5 Stars"
        else if keywordArray does not contain "5*****" and FiveStarPhotos contains {mediaItem} then
            syncSmartAlbum("5 Stars")
        end if
```